# Radixsort Algorithm - Scatter and Gather Methods

Tags: java, algorithm, function, sorting, methods

I have an assignment where I have to read a file, take each line as a node in a circular linked list and then run through `scatter()` and `gather()` methods. I'm not asking for any code specifically, rather I'm having trouble visualizing the concepts. I'll provide the directions given to me if anyone could maybe help clear up the terminology. **Please try not to give any code that specifically gives away the answer**, unless you're trying to explain something because this is a school assignment.

Now I'm having trouble with the next two methods, `scatter()` and `gather()`. Here are their comments I was provided in the file:

```
/**
     * Scatters entries of master list (referenced by instance field masterListReat) 
     * to buckets for a given pass.
     * 
     * Passes are digit by digit, starting with the rightmost digit -
     * the rightmost digit is the "0-th", i.e. pass=0 for rightmost digit, pass=1 for 
     * second to rightmost, and so on. 
     * 
     * Each digit is extracted as a character, 
     * then converted into the appropriate numeric value in the given radix
     * using the java.lang.Character.digit(char ch, int radix) method
     * 
     * @param pass Pass is 0 for rightmost digit, 1 for second to rightmost, etc
     */
    public void scatter(int pass) {
        // WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
    }

    /**
     * Gathers all the CLLs in all the buckets into the master list, referenced
     * by the instance field masterListRear
     * 
     * @param buckets Buckets of CLLs
     */
    public void gather() {
        // WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
    }
```

I'm already provided with an array of circular linked lists called `buckets[]`, which is initiated to `null`. The confusing part to me is what goes in the nodes of circular linked list of each bucket. Could someone help clear up the directions possibly for those last two methods and what exactly they are suppose to do?

Thanks.

Comment: This is verbatim copied from an assignment for Rutgers University CS 112. StackOverflow is not a place to ask broad homework questions. It's okay to ask for help with something specific, but this is an active form of academic dishonesty.

Comment: @JoeBoyle He asked for help understanding terminology and concepts, with a specific request to NOT give code. I don't think that's dishonest at all, any more than asking a tutor or the professor himself for better explanations.

Comment: @Douglas I understand that he asked for code not to be published. But there's a large difference between asking for general questions ("can you please explain xx process of RadixSort? My understanding is yy.") vs. posting an entire assignment. We're not a homework Q&A website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help understand the concepts of how radix sort works, let's describe how you might use it to sort a deck of cards.

Start with a deck of cards in random order. The deck has been thoroughly shuffled, but it's in a nice neat little stack. You take the top card off the deck and look at it. It's the 3 of hearts. You completely ignore the suit, and instead use only the number - you put this card in a stack designated for all 3s. You take the next card. It's the queen of spades. It goes in the previously empty queens stack. You take the next card, the 3 of clubs. You put it on top of the 3 of hearts. Continue in this way until you've gone through the whole deck. At the end, you will have 13 stacks, each containing 4 cards that all have the same number/letter but different suits.

The previous paragraph corresponds to your `scatter()` function.

Now you pick up the pile of 2s and put it back in the main deck. Then pick up the 3s and put them on top of the 2s. Then put the 4s on top of the 3s, then put the 5s on top, and so on up through kings and aces. You now have a single deck again, still completely random with regard to suit, but completely ordered with regard to number/letter.

The previous paragraph corresponds to your `gather()` function.

If you then repeat the `scatter()` step, but this time with four piles for the suits and ignoring number/letter, and then repeat `gather()`, the result will be a completely ordered deck.

Your code is supposed to do this with numbers instead of cards, with one stack (or `bucket`) per digit 0 through 9. The `pass` parameter is telling you which digit to `scatter()` by - ones digit, tens digit, hundreds, thousands, etc. `gather()` doesn't care about `pass`, it just puts the 0 bucket before the 1 bucket no matter which digit is involved.

Comment: Since these are a circular linked lists, the analogy should be to place the cards face down, so it's FIFO ordering (this keeps the sort stable).

Answer (score 0):

For scatter() and gather(), bucket[] is an array of the same type as masterListRear, each element of bucket[] is a pointer to the last node of a separate circular list.